# Laravel throws ReflectionException: Class config does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

(I know you may think this is a duplicate question but I really believe its not)

I am working on an API using Laravel and I had the code all sorted out and running. However out of the blues I run my test on day and I get

```
ReflectionException: Class config does not exist
```

whenever I try to store a new Model
I updated Laravel to 5.7 but the problem persisted
Then I thought this was a problem with the Database but

```
php artisan migrate
```

creates database tables successfully. Running out of time.

Comment: 5.7 hasn't been released yet ...

Comment: Are you sure? I have 5.7.* in my composer.json file

Comment: 5.7 has not been released yet ... you can access it, but it isn't released yet .. that is the point, its a development version, why are you using it?

Comment: I believe, I stated that my issue started before I updated

Comment: After checking the issues referenced by Afraz Ahmed, I found out that I did not have a _**bootstrap/cache/config.php**_. Is that an issue?

Comment: probably not ... is there no error log?

Comment: Just the Stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try**

```
php artisan clear-compiled
```

If it does not solve the issue then read this thread https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/99 and https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9733

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with phpunit 6.0:

https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/99

I suggest upgrading to php7.x and the latest phpunit. (I know. A pain, but there are great tutorials out there for the upgrade and if you follow them step by step, you will have it done in under a half hour.)

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was with the dependencies. What worked for me was to completely remove the vendor directory and do a composer update to re-install the dependencies and vendor packages.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting files in the `project/bootstrap/cache/` and then running:

```
$php artisan clear-compiled
```

solved my problem!