Laravel: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class config does not exist
I'm working on a codebase I inherited, after pulling the code from github and some minor changes I am able to get it to build and run using composer install using php artisan serve. However upon doing that when debug is enabled in my .env file I see the error Uncaught ReflectionException: Class config does not exist in .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:809
I've searched online and seen many troubleshoot this problem however none of the proposed solutions have worked for me. I've tried:

deleting the vendors folder and re-running composer install
deleting the boostrap/cache
composer update

If in the .env file I set APP_DEBUG=false the app runs but only loads a 404 page. Appreciate any suggests or help.Other useful details
php version: 7.3.33
composer version: 2.7.7
laravel version: 7.30.6

laravel version?

Without more information, my guess would be to use composer v1 and try to see whether this runs.

"... and some minor changes"?  What did you change?  Did it run before you inherited it?  Could your changes be related to the problem?  PHP 7.3 is quite old, is that the version the app was built for?  Laravel 8 was the last version that supported 7.3: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/releases, https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/releases

There was a reference../tests/Pusher.php in a test folder that isn't apart of the codebase in the index.php file .
also updated the original post with the version of laravel I'm running

There are many other questions here with answers about that error, have you been through all the suggested fixes?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57726803/fatal-error-uncaught-reflectionexception-class-config-does-not-exist, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51911111/laravel-throws-reflectionexception-class-config-does-not-exist, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73350551/class-config-does-not-exist-laravel-9, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54450618/reflectionexception-class-config-does-not-exist-on-update-to-laravel-5-7, https://stackoverflow.com/q/58398189/6089612 ...

Check config/app.php for missing or incorrect service providers. Also, ensure APP_KEY is set in .env.
If it still doesn't work, try:
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload

That should resolve the ReflectionException.
